# Exist db triggers: after-create-document event does not fire when a document is stored as a result of another trigger

Tags: exist-db

With Exist DB I am able to get triggers working. For example, in my setup adding a file to a collection A triggers an XQuery which reads this particular file and generates several new files based on the content of this file (to another collection B - sibling of A).

Next, I would like to set a trigger on collection B, which starts an XQuery for every file that's written into it.

If the file is written by / on behalve of the first trigger, this seems to be impossible. I can see that the files are written into collection B by the trigger on collection A, but then the after-create-document event does not fire. However, if I manually place a file into B with webdav, the event is fired.

Is this a fundamental limitation or is there a better way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a bug to me, can you file an issue on the GitHub issue tracker for the project: https://github.com/exist-db/exist/issues

Comment: Issue added to github. Please note that I'm not an Exist DB expert so it might all be a mistake on my part :-(